# Google Spreadsheet - How to import specific table from Wikipedia?

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping, import, google-sheets-formula, wikipedia

I'm currently using this to import a table from Wikipedia:

```
=IMPORTHTML("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2020%E2%80%9321_Premier_League";"table";6)
```

It takes the 6th table from that Wikipedia page, which is the "results table" for the Premier League (football). It nicely imports the data in a 21 row x 21 column matrix.

But from time to time, people add new tables to that Wikipedia page, changing the order of the tables. The target table no longer becomes the "6th table".

**Question:** Is there a different way to directly import the "results table" instead of the taking the table number? (I tried fooling around with the function  `importxml` but I don't know how to use XPath.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2020%E2%80%9321_Premier_League",
 "//table[@class='wikitable plainrowheaders']/tbody/tr")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. As a newbie, is it true when I say that I'm lucky that the table I needed is from the class "wikitable plainrowheaders"? Because it happens to be coincidentally the only table on that page with such a class.

Comment: not rly luck. every table has usually some unique identifier or class

Comment: Wikipedia is editable by everyone. I will go in and add an `id` if there isn't one